# Boolean function returning 24, and acting inconsistent across multiple compilers

Tags: c++, recursion

Alright, this is driving me nuts and I have no idea what's going on. I have some code I'm making for school that basically takes in a string and a start and end index, and spits out true if the string is a palindrome, and false if it isn't. I added some extra stuff to make sure that it works if you give it a sentence with spaces and punctuation, and besides a small logic error that makes it return true if the middle two letters are different, it works..... almost. It has a super funny error where it seems to act differently on different compilers. On repl.it, I get a `stack smash detected` message for basically any input, but for some things, like inputting `Hello, World!` I get a segmentation fault. When I run it on Visual Studios 2019 it returns 24 for every false input, I don't even know how a boolean even returns something like 24, but if I change the function from type `bool` to type `int`, then it works perfectly.... except for repl.it, where I still get stack smashing. I also don't want to just leave it at an int and call it a day because that feels like a bandaid, what the heck is going on??

tldr; Boolean function returning 24 on Visual Studios, and stack smashing on others, changing the function return type to int instead of bool fixes it on Visual Studios, but not for others.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrom(string, int, int);

int main() {

  string str = "R aceCar";// should return true
  bool thing = isPalindrom(str,0,str.length()-1);
   cout << thing << endl;


}

bool isPalindrom(string str, int start, int end){
  if(end - start == 1 && (tolower(str[start]) == tolower(str[end])) || start == end){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    if((str[start] >= 'a' && str[start] <= 'z') || (str[start] >= 'A' && str[start] <= 'Z')){
      if((str[end] >= 'a' && str[end] <= 'z') || (str[end] >= 'A' && str[end] <= 'Z')){
        
        if(tolower(str[start]) == tolower(str[end])){
         // cout << str[start] << ' ' << str[end] <<endl;
          isPalindrom(str, start+1, end-1);
        }
        else{
          return 0;
        }
      }
      else{
        isPalindrom(str, start, end -1);
      }
    }
    else{
      isPalindrom(str, start+1, end);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A couple things: You say "boolean returning a non boolean", but `isPalindrom` returns an `int`. Second: In a bunch of paths of execution, it doesn't return anything at all, which is undefined behavior. Note that just _calling_ `isPalindrom(str, start+1, end-1);` isn't the same as _calling and returning_ `return isPalindrom(str, start+1, end-1);`

Comment: Only 2 conditional paths return an int inside ```isPalindrom```. To make it work you should make sure, all paths have a return value. Instead of ```isPalindrom(str, start, end -1);``` use ```return isPalindrom(str, start, end -1);``` to return the result of that recursive call. You might also want to return ```bool``` instead of ```int``` using ```true``` or ```false``` instead of ```1``` or ```0```.

Comment: Where the code makes the recursive call `isPalindrom(str, start+1, end-1);` (for example), are you expecting it to return the value from that recursive call immediately? If so - *why should it do so*? Would you expect similarly if you called *any other function*? Recursive calls are *not special* - the interesting thing is *how function calls work, such that recursion is supported*.

Comment: Learn to write better question titles, please.

Comment: @NathanPierson I changed it to an int for a test, since on visual studio, using an int provided correct results, while using a bool returned `24`, I just forgot to change it back when posting my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are not returning a value from isPalindrom, - your compiler is surely warning you about it, mine did

> 1>C:\work\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(68): warning C4715: 'isPalindrom': not all control paths return a value

you probably - its your logic - just want

```
            if (tolower(str[start]) == tolower(str[end])) {
                // cout << str[start] << ' ' << str[end] <<endl;
               return  isPalindrom(str, start + 1, end - 1);  <<<<===
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
           return isPalindrom(str, start, end - 1); <<<<====
        }
    }
    else {
        return isPalindrom(str, start + 1, end); <<<<====
    }
```

with those edits your code now says 0 - which I assume means that "R ceCar" is not a palindrome

Also this really should be

```
 bool isPalindrome()
```

Comment: The `return 0;` is unreachable and unnecessary I think?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thas what I thought, but  nope - without it OP code still fails - didnt go ito it i depth tho, maybe I typod something

Comment: @AlanBirtles - i worked it out - I missed the naked call to isPalindrom after the tolower

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to do the returns how you did it, since in class we're learning about Binary searches and recursion, and the professor did his returns in a similar manner to how I did it.

Is the reason why I have to do it the way you did since I'm telling the function that it's a bool, that it has to return a value, and for my code, only the last call is returning a value?

Comment: @MmMmSsSs - no its because you have to return something from the function. Some of the logic paths through your code were not returning anything. If your professor says otherwise he is wrong, but I suspect you just misunderstood. My compiler complained about your original code. YOu demonstrated quite clearly that without the returns it failed, QED

Answer (score 1):

pm100's answer is the guidance you seek. But Another minor bug I spotted was your exit check at the beginning of the function:

```
if(end - start == 1 || start == end){
    return 1;
  }
```

Consider what happens when you have this simple test:

```
  string str = "AB";// should return false
  int thing = isPalindrom(str,0,str.length()-1);

  cout << thing << endl;
```

As you have it coded now, `isPalindrom` will return 1, but you really want it to return 0 since `"AB"` is not a palindrome.

There's a very simple fix. And if you have to code a complex solution for that edge case, you're doing it wrong. Let me know if you don't see the quick fix and I'll provide another hint.

And to make your recursion more efficient, you could avoid making a **copy** of `str` on every recursion by passing it as const reference:

```
int isPalindrom(const string& str, int start, int end)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that there is a logic error on my part with my exit status, but I was too consumed with the issue of it not working at all that I didn't bother fixing it lol, also yeah I forgot that I should be passing the string by reference for better practice, thank you for reminding me :)